# How to stop chart to plot a graph?

Tags: javascript, graph

I am using [AmCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) to build a line graph. I'm done with all functionality. But I need to stop the graph getting plotted when user clicks on the button. Since it is real time based data, I am not getting how to start with. Following is the link from where I learnt about time based real time data. As you can see here, the graph is getting plotted per second. If user would like to zoom in and analyse the graph data , he can't do it because data is updating each second. My problem is when user clicks on some button, let's say "Stop" then graph should stop plotting visually but for each second data should keep generating in background even though its not getting plotted. When user clicks on the "Continue" button it should plott all the data generated from "Stop" time to "Continue". Please give me a basic idea how can I achieve this?

```
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/ATQUm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a quick look over AmCharts API, I think you should validate data (calling validateData() method) based on a boolean condition: if you need or not to redraw the whole graph (condition updated when clicking on stop/continue buttons).

From [AmCharts API](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart):

**validateData()** - *This method should be called after data in your data provider changed or a new array was set to dataProvider. After calling this method the chart will parse data and redraw.*

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ATQUm/677/).

Sample code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="stopBtn" type="button" value="Stop"/>
<input id="continueBtn" type="button" value="Continue"/>
```

**JS**

```
var needsDrawing = true,
    stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn'),
    continueBtn = document.getElementById('continueBtn');

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    needsDrawing = false;
});

continueBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    needsDrawing = true;
});
```